# image upload functionality with apollo server 2 (graphql)

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

Herewith I need clarifications on **image upload** with **android** using **Apollo server 2** for API work.

Previously I followed **base64** conversion image-upload technic. But afterwards, I want to alter the file upload from previous on to in-built **graphql-server file upload feature**.

From internet searching, I can't get clear idea about how the file upload has to be implemented between android and graphql using the inbuilt file upload feature in apollo server.

So please anyone share your thoughts on it and redirect me to clear path to implement it correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've Searched a lot on **Android** File Uploading in **Apollo Server** using **GraphQL**.But In Apollo server we can Upload a image using **Base64** Format the only possible and easiest way is to use **Retrofit** .We can upload a file in Apollo server using **Retrofit POST**  Method in Android.